# How do I obtain urls from other pages under the same browser by using javascript? Is it possible at all?

Tags: javascript, browser

Suppose the user has several pages open under one browser. I want my page to be able to obtain the urls associated with the other pages by using javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible (unless it's privileged code as in an addon). That will be a huge privacy violation if possible.

Comment: I hope not. Why are you wishing to be nosey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would be a huge security/privacy leak. Of course not.